# Node reference into linked list like .Net has, to enable O(1) item insertion

Tags: java, linked-list, big-o

.Net's [`LinkedList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) has a <strike>nice</strike> basic linked list feature that allows me to keep a node reference, a "pointer" into a linked list so to speak, and use that reference to navigate and manipulate the linked list from there in an O(1) fashion. To wit:

```
LinkedList<string> linkedList = new LinkedList<string>();
LinkedListNode<string> cur = linkedList.First;
LinkedListNode<string> rememberThis = null;
do
{
    if (...)
        rememberThis = cur;
} while ((cur = cur.Next) != null);

if (rememberThis != null)
    linkedList.AddAfter(rememberThis, "added-value");
```

I'm failing to see how I can do the same in Java, namely

1. Iterating through a `LinkedList` (this of course is `O(n)`)
2. Making note of a list node
3. Use that node reference even after further iteration for `O(1)` insertion

Java does [`give me access`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#listIterator-int-) to a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html), which allows me to do manipulation of the list around the item where I'm at, but I cannot seem to iterate on, while holding on to a previous node.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If the `List` interface/implementation were as broken as you describe it, the Java world could not function, which clearly is not the case.  Look into `List.iterator()` to see how an iterator can be used in Java.  You can keep track of an element across which you come, and then act on this at a later point.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Looking at [`List.iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator--) does not tell me anything concerning my question. Can you be more specific? Or - as you claim I describe `List` as being broken - perhaps re-read my full question?

Comment: Give examples of operations you need to perform which `LinkedList` does not make possible.  Then the question might get interesting.

Comment: Could you update with a specific task you wish to do with the list.  I have the feeling that you find Java's `List` interface to be weird and kinky, not surprising coming from .NET.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something?

No. *LinkedList#ListItr* class doesn't have bookmark. So you cannot keep iterating on, while holding on to a previous node.
There's no O(1) method *addAfter(Node node, E element)* in *LinkedList*, because *LinkedList#Node* is private. There's *add(int index, E element)* which is O(n). Too sad.

<strike>A workaround is to use 2 ListIterator. One keep iterating on, the other one stops at the position you want to remember. Then you can use *ListIterator#add(E e)* in the end, which is O(1). But the first one cannot modify the list otherwise it'll break the second one.</strike>

Comment: The workaround however has about the same performance as 1) iteration, 2) remembering the index 3) doing `add(int index, E element)`. In fact, `add(int index, E element)` could even be somewhat faster, as it does not need to maintain an iterator.

Comment: @Eugene Beresovsky Agreed. i'll delete it.

Answer (score 0):

No, don't do that, that will breaks. If you ever modified the `LinkedList` *structurally* later, a `ConcurrentModificationException` will be thrown next time you move the `ListIterator`'s crusor, and there is no way around it. This is known as *fail-fast* behavior.

Anyway, Iterators aren't meant to hold a cursor in a list for a long time. And currently there is no way to hold a cursor to a certain position in a list, including `LinkedList`s, for a long time, even for openjdk 9 ea IIRC. The reason behind it *may* be the ambiguity of how to move the existing cursors. This may be obvious in manyq situations, but not always.

After all, it's (almost) impossible to add it to a superinterface of `LinkedList` (`Queue`,`Deque`,`List`) now.(This is clearly a API design fault!) You can create your own version of `LinkedList` to implement that.

If you really want to keep a reference, somehow. You will have to hack the internals with reflections, which may doesn't worth it at all.